# s-t min cuts intersection

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find the proof for the following network flow problem:

therer is a graph G = (V, E).If you have two s-t min cuts, show that their intersection is also a s-t mincut.
Make algorithm which finds s-t min cut with minimal number of vertices in s.

I understand that there is need to check somehow all edges from the cut, but how to do it more effectively? As for the algorithm I see that the desicion is to find intersection of all min cuts, but can't understand how to find all min cuts( with one I have no problems)

I'd be very glad to get some help with it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the claim: `If you have two s-t min cuts, show that their intersection is also a s-t mincut. ` Or how to use it for finding a minimal min cut?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please tag it as [homework].

Answer (score 5):

Clearly homework, so here's a hint. Prove that, given a max flow, an s-t cut is minimum if and only if its capacity with respect to the residual network is zero. The nice thing about zero-capacity cuts is that they're the ones whose outgoing arcs all have capacity zero, which is a local property instead of a global one. From here, the proof of the intersection property is a couple lines, and the algorithm is straightforward as well (it doesn't compute "all" s-t min cuts).